# Как изменить название дистрибутива?

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Компилирую ядро Raspbian, хочу изменить название системы. Т.е. после полной загрузки системы появляется

"Rasbian GNU/Linux raspberrypi tty

Login:"

Как изменить строчку Rasbian GNU/Linux raspberrypi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, это меняется в самой установленной системе в файле /etc/issue и /etc/issue.net - используется при подключении ssh